# React Native : Sample App crashes after upgrading to Mac 10.12.6

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, react-native

I recently updated my Mac to OS.12.6 Sierra.

Previously working React Native (*nothing fancy just their AwesomeProject sample app*) stopped working.

When I run `react-native run-ios` I am able to launch the simulator the app just appears, and then crashes back to the iphone app screen without any error messages.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled react-native-cli, upgraded brew, watchman and reinstalled node modules..but no luck

Anyone has any pointers on this ?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the app in simulator? Have you tried to clear watchman using `watchman watch-del-all`?

Comment: @wlisrausr yes...i have tried both of them (clearing watchman and deleting app from simulator)..its a puzzling one..right ? :)

Comment: Yeah, it is. So, you didn't modified anything inside this sample app?

Comment: what version of react-native are you using?

Comment: I did not make any changes...just did react-native init <appname>...after the app was generated...did a cd to that folder and started the emulator via react-native run-ios

Comment: I am using react-native-cli:2.0.1 and react-native: 0.48.0

Comment: xcode 8.3.3 and mac os sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the rootcause of the issue.

Looks like this is a bug with the latest version.

Facebook has acknowledged this as a bug.

The workaround is to create the project with an older version like 0.44

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15770

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues too after upgrading to Sierra 10.12.6.

I resolved by running `create-react-native-app <folder>`

And then I ejected it with `yarn run eject`

`yarn run ios` after, and the app seems stable.